# TF400424: Failed to send to Microsoft Outlook

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013, outlook-2013

When i try to send a work item from VS 2012 or 2013 to Microsoft Outlook 2013.

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Team Foundation Error

### TF400424: Failed to send to Microsoft Outlook: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

### OK

Probably there's something wrong with the TFS Add-in for Outlook. Did anybody solve this issue already?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to configure your `smtp server`, is located in `administration console` of tfs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I do not have tfs administration privileges but will check that with my admin.

Comment: I am not so confident about this suggestion, since it works on my collegues systems using the same tfs. I reinstalled VS2013. I will try the same with ms office.